# Qt creator: Icon Themes for QT5

Tags: qt, qt5

I am writing a QT5 application using QT Creator on MacOS. It seems there isn't a default icon theme availble. Is this true?

Follow up: If there isn't a default icon theme available are there resources available that one can pull in?